# How configure cakephp 2.4.x website in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have uploaded my cakephp files to my cpanel account. After that I run my website. then It shows an error telling some pdo mysql connect error. I checked my database.php file, correct data is given. Then again I run but again it showing same error.

```
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 262 → Mysql->connect()
CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php line 107 → DboSource->__construct(array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 3454 → ConnectionManager::getDataSource(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 1124 → Model->setDataSource(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 3476 → Model->setSource(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 2880 → Model->getDataSource()
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 2852 → Model->_readDataSource(string, array)
APP/Controller/AppController.php line 55 → Model->find(string, array)
[internal function] → AppController->beforeRender(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php line 248 → call_user_func(array, CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 925 → CakeEventManager->dispatch(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 194 → Controller->render()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(UsersController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
ROOT/public_html/index.php line 112 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Is there any problem with configuration of cakephp files in cpanel?
please give me a solution......

Comment: Have you checked if the php_pdo extension is installed?

Comment: Write phpinfo() in your script. And you if the PDO extension is loaded.

Comment: I run it. I think it is not loaded. Because I disabled pdo extention in my localhost and same problem occured as in my webserver. if the pdo_extention is not enabled then how can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution. In cpanel goto Softoculous (something lke that).In it there is frameworks option. Click on it.It will show all frameworks available. Install cakephp. After installation add your files in it(Controller,View,Model etc.). Now it will work

Answer (score 2):

To enable the PDO extension you have to enable it in your **php.ini**. If you use a Linux system its possible that the extension is loaded in an extra config file in your **/etc/php5/**.

If you use a Windows system find your **php.ini** and comment the line

`extension=php_pdo.dll`

after that changes you have to restart/reload your webserver or php processes.

Comment: I opened the /etc folder but I have not seen the php5 folder. All folders with hidden folders are checked not found. My server type is shared hosting.

Comment: In shared hosting its a bit complicated. You have to read the FAQ from your provider how to change the php.ini. Perhaps you can call the support.

Comment: I tested with these code for checking pdo enabled or not    <?php if (class_exists('PDO')) { echo "installed"; } else { echo "not installed"; } . It give the output as "installed.". Cakephp directory structure will vary from localhost to a webserver ??

Comment: Common problems and mistakes are that people that develop under Windows don't thing about the case of the classes. Under Windows you have case insensitivity and under Linux you have case sensitive. Perhaps this is a problem.